# How to use something like meta_query but for fields?

Tags: php, custom-field, meta-query

How to use something like meta_query but for fields?

This is my short code to understand me:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'nickname',
            'value' => $search,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$all_users = get_users($args);
```

How to make it working but by searching on user_login table not nickname meta?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Would you please elaborate your question a little bit more ? And what are referring to by  ***How to make it working but by searching on user_login table not nickname meta?*** ???

Comment: @the_dramatist I need to use something like meta_query but by searching the fields like user_login or user_login not searching the metas, Understand me?

Answer (score 0):

`get_users` is a wrapper for [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query), which offers some additional parameters for searching specific columns.

```
$args = array(
    'search'         => $search,
    'search_columns' => array( 'user_login' )
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Milo, I already try this by using your code this will be searching for the search word but my codes are to get the value and try to search it.
Example if I search for mil without o with you codes it will be not working because that I use meta value.
Hope you understand me and have a solution.

Comment: Your search term needs wildcards if it's not an exact match, like `'*' . $search . '*'`. See the [Search Parameters section for `WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Search_Parameters).